# More than one image causing margin shift of whole page

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything I know, and I still can't get it to work. I want the four images to be like in the screen shot, but a lot bigger (600px centered). When I do this, however, it causes the **entire** container to be shifted to the left for some reason unknown to me.

HTML snippet:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
    ..
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <div class="photos">
    <h2> Here are some photos.....</h2>
    <img src="img1">
    <img src="img2">
    ...
</div>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS snippet:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    background-color: #AAC1CC;
    max-width: 1440px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.content{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.photos {
    background-color: pink; /* for testing */
    width: 500px; /*for testing  - normally 100% */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.photos img{
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 3px #333;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

When the images are small (like 100px) the style is the same across the other tabs. However, if I increase the size of the images > 150px, the entire container shifts to the left by like ~20 pixels. I have tried using `<br>` between the images instead of `display:block` but it doesn't make a difference.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that when the images are larger they cause the browser to display a scroll bar. As you have set the container width to 100% and the window width is now slightly smaller this could cause the shift that you mention.

Comment: Bingo! This wouldn't have even crossed my mind - appreciate it. The easiest solution without losing responsiveness is to make the minimum height above the device height so that there's always a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a large image causing my main container to shift off center. threeandme's post reminded me to experiment with the overflow-y property in the css. I added  overflow-y: scroll; into the css for "body" and it stopped it from shifting for me.

Comment: OP wants to ask why does this happen?